Some of them "have no hair"
A list of five hidden "something" is given below. One is not on the list... Can you find it anyways?

1 RET 5
2 CON 6 
3 EON 6
4 LOW 7  
5 RINE 9


Just to check, does your 5th one definitely work for the extraction? Either I've got that one wrong or I'm getting a G instead of what you are hoping for... Thanks.

@Stiv Yes it does. No G. I just assumed it was a specific one, but I think M Oehm is right

Okay, well whatever M Oehm wrote (I'm assuming a comment) is gone, but if he posted what I think he posted then it had also crossed my mind... I'll write up an answer in case nobody else does in the meantime...

Pretty sure something to do with birds

@Stiv, I made a comment in passering that the fifth might be a group that comprises the majority of what the puzzle is about. Then I deleted it because I feared my use of "comprises" was wrong. On reflection and after consulting some dictionaries, I think it is okay. Anyway, if I had wanted to post my own answer, I wouldn't have made an obliqued comment. I'm sorry for the confusion.

@MOehm Aha, I see. Well my own oblique comment was meant to imply that I had come up with a second option (which I then subsequently used in my answer) but hadn't been sure because I thought it was more a 'family' rather than a specific species. Just to clear up any remaining mysteries!

The five "somethings" listed here are all...

 BIRDS. Specifically, what we see for each numbered row is a substring that appears at the end of its name, and a number showing the length of the name. So we have:

 1 RET 5 = EGRET
 2 CON 6 = FALCON
 3 EON 6 = PIGEON
 4 LOW 7 = SWALLOW
 5 RINE 9 = PASSERINE (this one gave me grief for a while, as I assumed it must be 'PEREGrine'...)

There is a sixth one hiding amongst them though, and we can find it by...

 ...using the first number on each line not just for ordering but also for indexing, taking the nth letter from each bird, like so:

EGRET, FALCON, PIGEON, SWALLOW, PASSERINE

 This spells out 'EAGLE', a bird which of course comes in a 'bald' variety, which is implied by the title: some of them have no hair!


Ahh I couldn’t find the last one

Well done :) I should've double checked the last one. I found it from a list with b names, not knowing it wasn't a specific b.

@Prim3numbah No problem :) I'm actually glad I was wrong in my first suggestion anyway, since that would have been very similar to the second. It's better this way :) (and it was still findable, clearly)

@Stiv Congratulations on 150k reputation!

@Will.Octagon.Gibson good size of which I am responsible for lol
